# Debugger for DSL

Tags: debugging, remote-debugging, dsl, dsl-tools

At my company, we have a DSL to represent a data flow network.  I'm looking into ways to make this environment more debuggable (not only native C++, since that would throw you out of the domain view).

Are there existing debugger 'frontends' that I can write an adapter for to e.g. break data flow, step forward one node, investigate edge contents, ...?

Answer (score 0):

You might find this paper on debuggers for DSLs useful: http://gray.cs.ua.edu/pubs/ldta-2007.pdf

In general, a good way to do this is to modify the DSL code generator to produce most of the debugger infrastructure necessary (for "debug" compiles).